# JQuery, need to split stringify json string into array

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have a string in JSON format. I want to split all the values into array.

```js
[{
  "sno": "1",
  "code": "bp150mb",
  "quantity": null,
  "name": "mudguard",
  "company": "bajaj",
  "vehicle": "pulsar",
  "brand": "1",
  "image": "N/A",
  "color": "Black",
  "price": "0"
}, {
  "sno": "7",
  "code": "P",
  "quantity": "5",
  "name": "",
  "company": null,
  "vehicle": "Not available",
  "brand": "1",
  "image": "N/A",
  "color": "-",
  "price": "0"
}]
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(str)` ..?

Comment: __split all the values__ into array??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarification. Do you mean you want to take each key-value pair in the string and put them into an array, or that you want to take each object and put it into an array as shown, or...?

Comment: Just provide the desired result for the given JSON string you provided, and your question will be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '[{"sno":"1","code":"bp150mb","quantity":null,"name":"mudguard","company":"bajaj","vehicle":"pulsar","brand":"1","image":"N/A","color":"Black","price":"0"},{"sno":"7","code":"P","quantity":"5","name":"","company":null,"vehicle":"Not available","brand":"1","image":"N/A","color":"-","price":"0"}]';
var array = $.parseJSON(str);
```

OR

```
var array = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
```

Since question asked for jQuery.

Comment: You don't declare things as `String`s in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```js
var jsonString = "[{\"sno\":\"1\",\"code\":\"bp150mb\",\"quantity\":null,\"name\":\"mudguard\",\"company\":\"bajaj\",\"vehicle\":\"pulsar\",\"brand\":\"1\",\"image\":\"N/A\",\"color\":\"Black\",\"price\":\"0\"},{\"sno\":\"7\",\"code\":\"P\",\"quantity\":\"5\",\"name\":\"\",\"company\":null,\"vehicle\":\"Not available\",\"brand\":\"1\",\"image\":\"N/A\",\"color\":\"-\",\"price\":\"0\"}]";
var parsedJsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(parsedJsonArray[0]['name']);
console.log(parsedJsonArray);
```

Comment: Hey @rahul yadav, Run code snippet and see the output you needed, let me know if still it not fulfilled your requirement, Thanks